# Click event - prevent capturing phase from child element

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, dom-events

I need to add a code snippet to an existing site (actually it's SharePoint site) with a button that starts a Javascript function on **click** event.
The problem is that SharePoint already has several **click** events attached to ***body*** element. Some of them fire before my function get executed and some of them after.

I need to make only my click event fire.

The function that starts after mine I manage to stopped by `stopPropagation()` function. But what can I do to stop functions that fire before my event?
I assume the idea is to somehow stop capturing from child element...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the click events attached to body to trigger when you click on the button, you can add a check in the event handlers attached to body click and stop the execution of code if your button is the originator of that event.

> if(event.target == document.getElementById("your_buton_id")){return;}

Comment: it's not my code that attaches events to body element so I cannot modify it